# Can you use ADO.NET SQLCommandBuilder with composite keys?

Tags: ado.net, sqlclient, sqlcommandbuilder

I have a database table with 6 columns. The primary key is a composite key made up of 5 of the 6 columns

I am trying to use the `SqlClient.SqlCommandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand` to delete the row.

However I am getting the following error:

> "System.InvalidOperationException : Dynamic SQL generation for the
>   DeleteCommand is not supported against a SelectCommand that does not
>   return any key column information."

The `SelectCommmand` contains all the columns in the table:

```
SELECT  TABLENAME.COL1, TABLENAME.COL2, TABLENAME.COL3, 
        TABLENAME.COL4, TABLENAME.COL5, TABLENAME.COL6
FROM TABLENAME
```

Could the problem be the composite key?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your problem is the composite key.  According to the documentation, the primary key does not have to be a single column.  There are other limitations that are required to automatically generate statements though.  Try reading through [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz(VS.80).aspx) to verify that you haven't missed anything.

Comment: Thanks, that is a useful document. Unfortunately none of the limitations mentioned seem to apply to my code.